# How to create array in Guzzle Request?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, curl, guzzle

I'm trying to send a post to an API, but the "items should be an array" error is returned.

```
  $response2 = $client2->request('POST', 'https://api.iugu.com/v1/invoices?api_token='.$token, [
      'form_params' => [
          'email' => $email,
          'due_date' => $due_date,
          'items' => ['description' =>
            'Item Um',
            'quantity' => 1,
            'price_cents' => 1000
          ],
          'payer' => [
            'cpf_cnpj' => $cpf_cnpj,
            'name' => $name,
            'phone_prefix' => $phone_prefix,
            'phone' => $phone,
            'email' => $email,
            'address' => [
              'zip_code' => $zip_code,
              'street' => $street,
              'number' => $number,
              'district' => $district,
              'city' => $city,
              'state' => $state,
              'country' => 'Brasil',
              'complement' => $complement
            ]
          ]
      ]
  ]);
```

I've tried it in several ways.

```
      ['items' => 'description' =>
        'Item Um',
        'quantity' => 1,
        'price_cents' => 1000
      ],
```

But none of the ways showed the result I wanted. It's weird, because when I run with PHP and CURL lib this code works like charm.

Any sugestion? Thanks in advance for community!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each item should be an array with their own description, quantity, and price_cents keys. Wrap each within one more array like so:

```
'items' => [
    [
       'description' => 'Item Um',
       'quantity' => 1,
       'price_cents' => 1000
    ],
]
```

[You'll get an array of items now](https://3v4l.org/kIOI8):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [description] => Item Um
            [quantity] => 1
            [price_cents] => 1000
        )

)
```

Comment: I found the error! It's 'json' instead 'form_params'.